# Checking unique list in a patchset

Tags: netlogo

I have each patch containing a list of length 4. For exaample

```
state = [ 1 0 1 4 ]
```

I want to check how many patches have such unique lists, given the order of elements in the list matters.

Thus, for example in each of 4 patches with the following:

```
[1 2 4 1] [ 1 2 2 3] [1 3 2 2] [1 2 4 1]
```

The output should be 3.

Comment: I don't understand the question. _Why_ is the answer 4? What does "how many patches have such unique lists" mean?

Comment: I don't understand either. I have the same questions as Seth.

Comment: Oh really sorry. It should be three.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it:

```
length remove-duplicates [state] of patches
```

Comment: Great! This is amazing. I never thought of it this way. Thanks!